# Twisted HTTP client to download a whole page and measure the download time

Tags: http, twisted

I tried to use the Twisted Agent in order to implement HTTP client and download a full web page of a specific URL, finally, measure the load time of that particular web page. Unfortunately, the code I have come up with doesn't follow the inner URLs in HTML tags so a web page which it takes 10 sec to be loaded completely after downloading some contents even from other websites on a browser will take less than a second to be fully loaded in my code, which shows my code is not correct! Even when I used BrowserLikeRedirectAgent and RedirectAgent the result is the same. Any comment is appreciated.

```
def init_http(url):
    userAgent = 'Twisted/%s (httpclient.py)' % (version.short(),)
    agent = BrowserLikeRedirectAgent(Agent(reactor))

    def response_time_calculator(test,t1):
        end_time = time.time()
        response_time = end_time - t1
        print ("Got the Whole page in:  ", response_time)

    start_time = time.time()

    d = agent.request(
        b'GET', str(url), Headers({'user-agent': [userAgent]}))
    def cbResponse(response):
        if response.length is not UNKNOWN_LENGTH:
            print('The response body will consist of', response.length, 'bytes.')
        else:
            print('The response body length is unknown.')
        d = readBody(response)
        d.addCallback(response_time_calculator, start_time)
        return d
    d.addCallback(cbResponse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.clock` only measures wallclock time on Windows (bizarrely).  Use `time.time` which measures wallclock time on all platforms.

Also, you have to implement the part where you follow links.  `Agent.request` downloads exactly the resource you request.  If that resource is some HTML with links to other resources, you have to parse the data, extract the links, and follow them.

You may want to look in to scrapy. If not, you can add a slightly smaller (less featureful) dependency like `html5lib`.  Something like:

```
    d = readBody(response)
    d.addCallback(load_images)
    d.addCallback(response_time_calculator, start_time)

...

from twisted.internet.defer import gatherResults
import html5lib

def load_images(html_bytes):
    image_requests = []
    doc = html5lib.parse(html_bytes)
    for img in doc.xpath("//img"):
        d = agent.request(img.src)
        d.addCallback(readBody)
        image_requests.append(d)
    return gatherResults(image_requests)
```

I've omitted proper url resolution (ie, handling relative links in the img src) and haven't actually tested this.  It probably has many bugs but hopefully makes the idea clear.

Comment: Thanks for the time.clock, I just need the <img> tags to be loaded, so their address can not be fed back to the Twisted agent, any workaround about it? I would rather not to implement a new library in my code, so using scrapy is not what I desired, I look for a solution to handle the problem with Twisted and Python alone.

Comment: If you don't want to use scrapy, you need to do something like parse the html, find the img tags, interpret their sources, and issue new `Agent.request` calls.  There's nothing in Twisted that will do this link following for you.  There also isn't really an html parser in Twisted.  There's a very old, not-so-great one in the stdlib but I'd really recommend you use `html5lib` which implements the html5 spec and is the only sane way to parse html these days.